# How to get all oAuth2.0 details for POSTMAN REST API?

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, postman

How can i get oAuth 2.0 details for magento 1.9.2.3,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Advanced, enable Mage OAuth. Clear cache. You need to create a REST account. That's  it for OAuth. Iam not sure of OAuth version.

Comment: Yes i did, still not working @Mahesh V